# Vue Server-Sided Rendering Hot Module Reloading Support for new modules

Tags: webpack, vue.js, hot-module-replacement, webpack-dev-middleware, webpack-hot-middleware

`Vue` offers a [HackerNews](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0) example to demonstrate how to do server-sided rendering along with hot module reloading support.

Basically, the client and server side code are split into two files: 
are compiled into two json files `entry-client.js` and `entry-server.js`. Then two webpack configs are written for each and they would be compiled into JSON files.

Then, there's the server `server.js` which makes use of `vue-server-renderer` to process the two JSONs and serve the contents.

As for hot module reloading, there's a config called [setup-dev-server.js](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/blob/master/build/setup-dev-server.js) inside the `build` folder which handles the task and stores the compiled content inside `webpack-dev-middleware`'s file system.

This setup works perfectly as long as you only make changes to `entry-client.js` and `entry-server.js` and their associated modules. However, what I want to do is adding a new module that is used by only `server.js` along with hot module reloading support.

An example would be adding a RESTful API, `entry-api.js`:

```
export function apiRoutes(app) {
  app.get('/hihi', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ status: 'hmr hi hitest success' }));
  });
  app.get('/byebye', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ status: 'hmr bye byetest success' }));
  });
}
```

And in `server.js`:

```
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
// ...
const app = express()

// ...
if (isProd) {
  const template = fs.readFileSync(templatePath, 'utf-8')
  const bundle = require('./dist/vue-ssr-server-bundle.json')
  const clientManifest = require('./dist/vue-ssr-client-manifest.json')
    renderer = createRenderer(bundle, {
    template,
    clientManifest
  })
  apiRoutes = require('./dist/api-bundle.js')
  apiRoutes(app)
} else {
  readyPromise = require('./build/setup-dev-server')(
    app,
    templatePath,
    (bundle, api, options) => {
      renderer = createRenderer(bundle, options)
    }
  )
}
// ...
app.get('*', isProd ? render : (req, res) => {
  readyPromise.then(() => render(req, res))
})
```

I managed to write a webpack config for compiling `entry-api.js` which works perfectly for production build. As for hot module reloading, any changes to code associated with `entry-api.js` does trigger a recompilation but the changes never reflection in real-time. Can someone show me what changes should I make to `set-dev-server.js` to make it work?

Reference:

My webpack config for `entry-api.js`:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const base = require('./webpack.base.config')
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

module.exports = merge(base, {
  target: 'node',
  devtool: '#source-map',
  entry: './src/entry-api.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'api-bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
  // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#externals
  // https://github.com/liady/webpack-node-externals
  externals: nodeExternals({
    // do not externalize CSS files in case we need to import it from a dep
    whitelist: /\.css$/
  }),
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
    })
  ]
})
```

I also opened an [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/issues/294) on GitHub, which I doubt would get any response.